# How to search inside a SQL table for a phrase

Tags: mysql

I am currently using MySQL but I am willing to migrate if necessary to any solution suggested.

I am looking for an easy way to implement a search on a table.

The table has multiple entries with data similar to what will be found on user accounts, like names, addresses, phone numbers and a text column that contains comments of arbitrary length.

I want to make a search so that I can go over all rows and columns and find the best matching row. Slightly misspells corrected (Not very important). But most important is the ability to cross search everything.

Table can have as many as 20,000 rows.

Search parameter will be for example: "Company First Name"

Expected results:

> company|Contact First Name|Address|...|...

example 2, slightly misspelled search parameters : "Pinaple Street Compani"

Expected results row:

> company|pinapple street|..|...
>   companie|pinapple street|..|...
>   company|pinaple street|..|...

EDIT:

Forgot to clarify that multiple searches will be done at the same time so it has to be fast (Around 100 searches at the same time). Also the language of the data is not english and the database is utf8 with support for non-english characters

Comment: There's no simple solution. You have to write `WHERE col1 LIKE '%pattern%' OR col2 LIKE '%pattern%' OR ...`. It will not be efficient, and it won't do any spelling correction.

Comment: Please show a) sample table data, b) your expected output, and c) what query you have already tried.

Comment: Have a look at [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: You could use full-text searching, but having a full-text index on every column will probably be lots of overhead.

Comment: For the misspelling problem, you could try to reduce the indexed words using some function like [soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: Of course you do NOT create a fulltext index on every column, but add a single column where you put all the text to be searched for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misspelling problem is hard, if not impossible, to solve well in pure MySQL.

The multiple-column `FULLTEXT` search isn't so bad.

Your query will look something like this ...

```
 SELECT column, column
   FROM table
  WHERE MATCH(Company, FirstName, LastName, whatever, whatever) 
      AGAINST('search terms' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

It will produce a bunch of results, ordered by what MySQL guesses is the most likely hit first. MySQL's guesses aren't great, but they're usually adequate.

You'll need a `FULLTEXT` index matching the list of columns in your `MATCH()` clause. Creating that index looks like this.

```
ALTER TABLE book 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX Fulltext_search_index_1 
    (Company, FirstName, LastName, whatever, whatever);
```

Comments in your question notwithstanding, you just need an index for the group of columns which you will search.

20K rows won't be a big burden on any recent-vintage server hardware.

Misspelling:  You could try `SOUNDEX()`, but it's an early 20th century algorithm designed by the Bell System to look up peoples' names in American English. It's designed to get many false positive hits, and it really is dumber than a bucket of rocks.

If you really do need spell correction you may need to investigate Sphinx.

Comment: Please look at the edit about why Soundex won't work. I read somewhere about Levistein distance and some other distance measures. Would these work on Multicolumn, text and big phrase search.